# JTabbedPane with banner on the top

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

please help create Layout;

I wont to create tabs(JTabbedPane) and on the top frozen image (like banner).

> '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>           BANNER
>   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
>   Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3

From first I created

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.CENTER);
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", makePanel1());
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab2", makePanel1());
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab3", makePanel1());
```

now add tabbedPane  to frame.
but tabs show in frame and I didn't have any place for my banner (image file).

Answer (score 3):

Create a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`. Place the banner to `SOUTH` and the `tabbedPane` in the `CENTER`. Then add the panel to your frame rather than adding the `tabbedPane` directly.

Comment: @dic19 no, not NORTH... [PAGE_START](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) :-)

Comment: @dic19 yes. you both are right. SOUTH is wrong place:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a grid layout with one column.

Add your banner first and then the Tab panel.
Add your grid layout to the frame.

But you'll have the same height for banner et tabs. Better go with StanislavL answer (Place the banner to NORTH since you want it on top).
In `BorderLayout`, the `CENTER` will take as most place as it can filling the space under your banner.